# CSV to JSON using a custom format

Tags: json, pandas, csv

I am attempting to create a JSON file from a CSV using Pandas

**CSV File**
This is just an excerpt, sorry for the long table, but I wanted to show things more clearly.

| Month | Type | Subtype | ItemName |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| December | ObjectTypeA | SubType A1 | Item 1 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeA | SubType A1 | Item 2 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeA | SubType A2 | Item 3 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeA | SubType A2 | Item 4 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeA | SubType A2 | Item 5 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeA | SubType A3 | Item 6 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeA | SubType A3 | Item 7 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeA | SubType A4 | Item 8 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeA | SubType A4 | Item 9 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeA | SubType A4 | Item 10 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeA | SubType A4 | Item 11 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeA | SubType A4 | Item 12 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeA | SubType A5 | Item 13 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeA | SubType A5 | Item 14 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeA | SubType A5 | Item 15 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeB | SubType B1 | Item 16 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeB | SubType B1 | Item 17 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeB | SubType B2 | Item 18 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeB | SubType B2 | Item 19 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeB | SubType B2 | Item 20 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeB | SubType B3 | Item 21 |  |
| December | ObjectTypeB | SubType B3 | Item 22 |  |
| March | ObjectTypeA | SubType A1 | Item 23 |  |
| March | ObjectTypeA | SubType A1 | Item 24 |  |
| March | ObjectTypeA | SubType A2 | Item 25 |  |
| March | ObjectTypeA | SubType A2 | Item 26 |  |
| March | ObjectTypeA | SubType A2 | Item 27 |  |
| March | ObjectTypeA | SubType A3 | Item 28 |  |
| March | ObjectTypeA | SubType A3 | Item 29 |  |
| March | ObjectTypeA | SubType A4 | Item 30 |  |
| March | ObjectTypeA | SubType A4 | Item 31 |  |
| March | ObjectTypeA | SubType A4 | Item 32 |  |
| March | ObjectTypeA | SubType A4 | Item 33 |  |
| March | ObjectTypeA | SubType A4 | Item 34 |  |
| March | ObjectTypeC | SubType C1 | Item 35 |  |
| March | ObjectTypeC | SubType C1 | Item 36 |  |
| March | ObjectTypeC | SubType C2 | Item 37 |  |
| March | ObjectTypeC | SubType C2 | Item 38 |  |
| March | ObjectTypeC | SubType C3 | Item 39 |  |

**Required Output**

```
allobjects: {
"December": {
    "Object Type A": {
        "Subtype A1": ["Item1","Item2"],
        "Subtype A2": ["Item3","Item4","Item5"],
        "Subtype A3": ["Item6","Item7"],
        "Subtype A4": ["Item8","Item9"],
        "Subtype A5": ["Item10","Item11","Item12"]
        },
                
    "Object Type B": {
        "Subtype B1": ["Item13","Item14"],
        "Subtype B2": ["Item16","Item15","Item17","Item18"],
        "Subtype B3": ["Item19","Item20"],
        "Subtype B4": ["Item21","Item22"],
        "Subtype B5": ["Item23","Item24","Item25"]
        },
    "Object Type C": {
        "Subtype C1": ["Item26", "Item27"],
        "Subtype C2": ["Item28", "Item29"],
        "Subtype C3": ["Item30", "Item31"]
        }},
"March": {
    "Object Type A": {
        "Subtype A1": ["Item32","Item33"],
        "Subtype A2": ["Item34","Item35"],
        "Subtype A3": ["Item36","Item37"],
        "Subtype A4": ["Item38","Item39","Item40"],
        "Subtype A5": ["Item41","Item42","Item44"]
        },
                
    "Object Type C": {
        "Subtype C1": ["Item45", "Item46"],
        "Subtype C2": ["Item47", "Item48"],
        "Subtype C3": ["Item49", "Ite50"]
        }},
    },
```

**Current Code**

```
df = pd.read_csv("Book4.csv", dtype={
            "Month" : str,
            "Type" : str,
            "Subtype" : str,
            "ItemName": str,
        })


compiled = []

for (month, type, subtype), bag in df.groupby(["Month", "Type", "Subtype"]):
    contents = bag.drop(["Month", "Type","Subtype"], axis=1)
    allitems = [list(row) for i,row in contents.items()]
    compiled.append(dict([(month, {}),
                        (type, {}),
                        (subtype, allitems),
                         ]))
with open("Book4_pandas.json", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps(compiled, sort_keys=False, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ') ))
```

**Output from Current Code**

```
[
  {
    "December": {},
    "ObjectTypeA": {},
    "Subtype A1": [
       [ "Item1",
             "Item2"
           ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "December": {},
    "ObjectTypeA": {},
    "Subtype A2": [
       [ "Item3",
             "Item4",
         "Item5"
           ]
    ]
  },

.......This goes on for december and then

  {
    "March": {},
    "ObjectTypeA": {},
    "Subtype A1": [
       [ "Item23",
             "Item24"
           ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "March": {},
    "ObjectTypeA": {},
    "Subtype A2": [
       [ "Item25",
             "Item26",
         "Item27"
           ]
    ]
  }
]
```

I appreciate that the JSON format is non-standard; however, I figured that writing a dict would be one "easy" approach? I believe there is an error in the way the for loop is structured?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create Series filled by `list`s by aggregation and then in nested dict comprehension create expected ouput:

```
s = df.groupby(["Month", "Type", "SubType"], sort=False)['ItemName'].agg(list)

compiled = {i: {j[1]: h[j].to_dict() 
                for j, h in g.groupby(level=[0,1], sort=False)}
                for i, g in s.groupby(level=0, sort=False)}
```

---

```
print (compiled)

{
    'December': {
        'ObjectTypeA': {
            'SubType A1': ['Item 1', 'Item 2'],
            'SubType A2': ['Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5'],
            'SubType A3': ['Item 6', 'Item 7'],
            'SubType A4': ['Item 8', 'Item 9', 'Item 10', 'Item 11', 'Item 12'],
            'SubType A5': ['Item 13', 'Item 14', 'Item 15']
        },
        'ObjectTypeB': {
            'SubType B1': ['Item 16', 'Item 17'],
            'SubType B2': ['Item 18', 'Item 19', 'Item 20'],
            'SubType B3': ['Item 21', 'Item 22']
        }
    },
    'March': {
        'ObjectTypeA': {
            'SubType A1': ['Item 23', 'Item 24'],
            'SubType A2': ['Item 25', 'Item 26', 'Item 27'],
            'SubType A3': ['Item 28', 'Item 29'],
            'SubType A4': ['Item 30', 'Item 31', 'Item 32', 'Item 33', 'Item 34']
        },
        'ObjectTypeC': {
            'SubType C1': ['Item 35', 'Item 36'],
            'SubType C2': ['Item 37', 'Item 38'],
            'SubType C3': ['Item 39']
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
with open("Book4_pandas.json", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps(compiled, sort_keys=False,
                             indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question. You can change your code like below :

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv("Book4.csv", dtype={
    "Month": str,
    "Type": str,
    "Subtype": str,
    "ItemName": str,
})


compiled = []

s = df.groupby(["Month", "Type", "Subtype"])['ItemName'].agg(list)

compiled = {level: {le: s.xs((level, le), level=[0, 1]).to_dict()
                    for le in s.index.levels[1]}
            for level in s.index.levels[0]}

with open("Book4_pandas.json", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps(compiled, sort_keys=False,
                             indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

Comment: I remove this solution from my answer [check](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68801578/revisions) because wrong ouput. If also copied json output you can see it.